# Fogbugz: A way to pre-fill custom fields via HTTP post?

Tags: fogbugz, fogbugz-api

Greetings!

Situation:
We have a CRM system that generates unique customer IDs. Now we added a field "customer match code" to our Fogbugz cases, using the Custom Fields Plugin.
In the CRM we have a button "Add case to customer" that launches a VB script to open a URL, ie. Fogbugz.

Obviously, it would be nice to pre-fill the custom field "customer match code" with the ID. Normal fields are easy to pre-fill:

```
http://devserver/fogbugz/default.asp?command=new&pg=pgEditBug&sTitle=MyTitle
```

Since the field is a custom field, I found it not in the table "Bug", but in "Plugin_6_CustomBugData", where it is called "customerxmatchxcodeX62".
Neither accessing "customerxmatchxcodeX62", nor "customer match code", nor "Customer Match Code" worked.

Does anyone know of a way to access custom fields like this?

Note: I am aware of the XML API. I'm trying to avoid it in this case, because all I want to do is open a browser with Fogbugz "new case" page and fill this one field.

Thank you for any helpful responses!
Best regards,
Robin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/ Try this site instead =)

Comment: Good point! :) Not exactly "the" answer, but helpful anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @Robin did you find an answer? If so it would be helpful to add a link to it or add it here, thanks.

Comment: @ChrisB: You realize this was five years ago? Sorry, I really don't remember how/if we solved that. Also, Fogbugz will have developed in the meantime, so whatever was true back then, may no longer be true now.